# How can i fetch data from mysql and render it with nodejs and javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, fetch-api

SOS question pls :
I want to make a simple todo app to add a todo task and save it in database mysql exactly like this link :
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_todolist.asp

But i want to save the data in mysql database instead of li html tag , and directly render it when i click add (submit button) like in the e.g above !!
The problem is that i can’t find the way who i can create a new li element in nodejs or who i can handle the rows of data after i connect with my database !!
Anybody has a hint please ! SOS

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) This question is far too broad for SO's Q&A format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to SO!

Im not sure whether I understand what are you trying to accomplish, but generally, your data flow should be like this:

**store data in database:**

- add event handler on button which will use JS to get task string you entered, store it in variable and pass this variable using REST API ( XMLHttpRequest for example ) to your server ( Express is good nodejs FW )
- server now connects to Pool and sends data to particular table, once done, youll get HTTP response from server

**get data from database:**

- using the same button event handler - after you receive http200 - you start to be creating

  elements using JS and appending string you received as response along with http status to it.

**confusing part** - why would you want to engage database, when everything you want to acchieve is to append new task to task list underneath the form ?

> EDIT to explain API data flow further:

**frontend:**

Firstly you need on click handler for your button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="createNewProject()">Click Me!</button>
```

It will call similar function:

```
let createNewProject = () => {
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() //REST API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest
const method = "post" //HTTP request method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods
const uri = "/createnewproject" //URI which you use to communicate with backend

//putting data you want to send to server together: 
newProject = {}
newProject.project_name = document.getElementById("modal_project_name").value
newProject.project_description = document.getElementById("modal_project_description").value

//send REST request: 
xhr.open(method, uri)
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(newProject))

//receive response from server and handle it on frontend: 
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
        //do whatever your frontend needs to do
    }
}
```

**server:**

```
// please note that HTTP request type and URI do match with frontend
app.post("/saveproject", (req, res) => {
    let savedProject = req.body; //get data from frontend
    persistence.saveProject(savedProject, status => {
        res.status(status).send(); //send to persistence
    });
});
```

**persistence:**

using PG here. Youre gonna need to create connection config file with address of your db server and connection ( based on db type, follow documentation ) and of course import whatever needs to be imported on node side.

```
module.exports.createNewProject = (newProject, callback) => {
// queryText: SQL query
// queryValues: your data
const queryText = "INSERT INTO projects (project_name, project_description, project_statuses_id, updated_date) VALUES ($1, $2, (SELECT id FROM project_statuses WHERE project_status = 'active'), $3)"
const queryValues = [
    newProject.project_name,
    newProject.project_description,
    newProject.updated_date
]

pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("PERSISTENCE: ", err)
        done(err)
        callback(400)
        return console.error("POOL CONNECTION ERROR", err.code)
    }
    client.query(queryText, queryValues, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("PERSISTENCE: ", err)
            done(err)
            callback(400)
            return console.error("QUERY ERROR", err.code)
        }
        done()
        callback(200) //return HTTP response back to frontend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
    })
})
```

Comment: Thx for your feedback, i use express js FW , and i know how to connect to server and to my Database but how can the server sending data to particular table ?! Coz i can’t use like (document.createElement) in nodejs .. DOM & back end issue , so can you give an example pls , (how to handle the output of data in li elements in nodejs) ,

Comment: @ShadiAmr express does not connect to server, express IS server. You create pool connection to your db, check documentation and let me know if anything comes up. Express ( or server ) wont createElements, you receive response from server API on your frontend - and frontend is where you manage html. Let me know if it does not make sense.

Comment: Oké , sounds perfect , but in the last step : module.exports = getConnection; can i recieve this in front end js file to make my layout html !?

Comment: @ShadiAmr I edited my post to explain further, hope it helps.

Comment: Anyway i’ll try it and will tell you what goes up , thx man